# How to write this using regular expression?

Tags: regex

I am looking for a regex to match a string like this: `1,2,4-6,9,11-13,20`.

Restrictions:

1. Only numbers, comma and hyphen are allowed
2. no spaces are allowed

Comment: Some clarification needed (along with perhaps an indication of what you've tried yourself and where exactly you're stuck. The problem might be that you haven't sufficiently defined what the actual problem is. If you do that, the solution is trivial). For example, would `-,1-,,2-2-2-2,111,-11-,-,-,34,` be valid? According to your rules so far, it would be. Is `1.5` a number? Also, do you want to *find* a string like this in a longer text, or do you want to *validate*  an entire string according to your rules?

Comment: And, as @FailedDev noted in his answer, you do need to tell us the regex flavor you're using.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is rather vague. I would suggest improving it, or reading a [tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) on regexes.

Based on your restriction your regex is `/^[-\d,]*$/` but I am quite sure that this is not what you want.

You should provide examples of input, output, the regex flavor you will be using and last but not least your attempts to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing you want to match comma seprated lists of positive integers or positive integer ranges. `\d+` matches integers, to allow ranges, you'd use `\d+(-\d+)?`.

So, the regex

```
\d+(-\d+)?(,\d+(-\d+)?)*
```

would do.

Comment: That would be my guess too. Would have been nice to hear it from @ggk517, though. But this is definitely worth an upvote.